# Kendo UI Multiselect post data is not coming, list count=0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am not able to get Kendo UI Multiselect's value in controller. it gives me length of list as 0. **MultiSelect is as:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Technicians)
                            .Name("Technicians")
                            .Placeholder("Select Technician(s)")
                            .DataTextField("Name")
                            .DataValueField("ID")
                            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                            .AutoBind(true)
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("GetTechnicians", "Project");
                                })
                                .ServerFiltering(false);
                            })
                            .BindTo(Model.Technicians)          
                        )
```

Technicians is :  **public List Technicians{get; set;}** in model

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well.

We ended up creating an `IEnumerable<int>` of Ids in the viewmodel to store that value.

So, in our instance

`public IEnumerable<PersonLookupViewModel> TaggedPersons { get; set; }`  (this is the list of people with IDs that I really want - contains first/last/id)

`public IEnumerable<int> PeopleToTag { get; set; }`  (this is the IEnumerable Int of the view model solely for posting the ints to the controller)

My view looked like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">       
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.taggedPersons)
  @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.PeopleToTag, 
     new SelectList(Model.CommitteeMembers, "PersonId", "FullName"))                  
</div>
```

and the JS wire up

```
$("#PeopleToTag").kendoMultiSelect({ "dataTextField": "FullName", "dataValueField": "PersonId", "placeholder": "Tag or Untag Persons to Action Item" });
```

So switching it to a ListBoxFor(model = > model.PeopleToTag) which was my Ienumerable field in my viewmodel solely to be able to get the data in the controller.  I then used automapper to create the Person model I actually needed.

I'm not sure if this is the *best* way, but it worked for us.